# Interchanging the first and last digits of a number in C

Tags: c, swap

Interchanging the first and last digits of a number in C.
 I cracked the question using most basic knowledge of c.
 I haven't used any strings or arrays or bit-wise operator, just simple     logic. for clearer understanding take an example and see.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a,x,y,n=1,b;
   printf("enter no");
   scanf("%d",&a);
   b=a;                //used further
   if(a>0)
   {
      y=a%10;           //last digit
   }
   while(a>0)
   {
      x=a%10;
      if(a>0 && a<=9)
      {
         x=a;         //first digit
      }
      a=a/10;
      n=n*10;
   }
   n=n/10;
   printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n",b,n,x,y);  //just to confirm readings
   b=(b-y);  
   b=(b+x);  
   b=b-(x*n);   
   b=b+(y*n);  
   printf("%d",b);   
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where your issue is, but this did make me think of an easier approach.  Why don't you use `sprintf` to convert the number to a string, then swap the first and last character?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the last digit is `0`?

Comment: `printf("%d",&b);` --> `printf("%d",b);` You're printing the address of `b`, you want to print `b`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ooh I didn't know about codereview SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope already you know what to fix: `printf("%d",&b)`.

Just for information. You could do it more simply:

```
int num;
scanf("%d",&num);

char snum[50];

// convert to string
int len = sprintf(snum, "%d", num);

// character swap
char temp = snum[0];
snum[0] = snum[len-1];
snum[len-1] = temp;

// convert to int or use the snum string
int result = atoi(snum);
printf("%d\n", result);
```

Comment: yes i saw that silly mistake. thanks.

Comment: `itoa()` is not a standard C library function.

Comment: This method fails when the reversed string overflows `atoi()` like when `num == 1234567899`.  Could simply use `printf("%s\n", snum);`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be simpler (I omit for sake of simplicity all checks on number range, functions return values and so on):

```
char digit, number[10]; //the maximum int is usually about 2 billions, so 9 digits, plus '\0'
scanf("%s", number);
digit=number[0];
number[0]=number[strlen(number)-1];
number[strlen(number)-1]=digit;
printf("%s", number);
```